# RDFa microdata or structured markup for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, breadcrumbs, rdfa, structured-data

According to this recent post on Search Engine Watch

https://searchenginewatch.com/2016/07/19/the-complete-beginners-guide-to-schema-org-markup-2

RDFa is a form of micro data to embellish a web page ( or blog post ? )

yet when I search for an RDFa plugin from the wordpress dashboard, all I see for RDFa is described as a means of adding breadcrumbs...

OK so breadcrumbs are, apparently, a function of RDFa.. but isn't micro data structured markup a lot more than "just" breadcrumbs?

Answer (score 0):

**RDFa** and **Microdata** are both *syntaxes* for publishing **structured data**. They define attributes that can be added to HTML elements.

**Schema.org** is a *vocabulary* that can be used with these (and other) syntaxes. It only defines terms (i.e., URIs like `http://schema.org/Person` and `http://schema.org/name`), which can be used in these syntaxes.

An example in RDFa that says that a person has the name "Alice" (where *person* and *name* are defined by Schema.org):

```html
<div vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="Person">
  <span property="name">Alice</span>
</div>
```

If you want to use RDFa in WordPress, you have different options:

- Add the RDFa to your theme.
- Add the RDFa in your content (editing as HTML).
- Use a plugin that does one or both of the above.

Neither RDFa nor Schema.org are restricted to marking up breadcrumbs (as the example above shows). A reason why RDFa breadcrumb plugins might be popular is that for a long time Google only supported RDFa (and not Microdata) for their [breadcrumb rich result](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumbs), which is no longer the case.

Comment: (Note that it’s off-topic on Stack Overflow to ask for plugin recommendations. [softwarerecs.se] would be an appropriate place for that.)